# Eclipse writing to .gvfs directory results in empty file

Tags: 10.10, eclipse, gvfs

I use Eclipse IDE (Zend Studio to be exact) for editing code on my development servers.

Because we have internal development servers, I connect to them via SSH and use the .gvfs folder in my home directory to access the files through Eclipse.
I.e: `/home/s.rees/.gvfs/sftp for s.rees on internal.dev/var/www`

Before upgrading to 10.10 Maverick I was fine reading and writing the files, but now any time it goes to save a file I get an empty file as a result. Making it impossible to do any work...

I don't know if this is a bug or a wacky feature (that can be disabled?)... or where I need to report it as such if it is a bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Just noted that this is happening also with other editors such as IntelliJ IDEA, GEdit and so on. Problem definitely on 10.10 since was ok on 10.04

I guess that there is a bug in GVFS.

Comment: linked bugs: http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg2560750.html and http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg2560450.html

Comment: Yeah, this is the bug I reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-vfs/+bug/658069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Valorin who asked the question commented, this is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-vfs/+bug/658069 The rest should be followed there.